# Как читать большой файл от какого-то одного места до другого?

Tags: c#, .net

Добрый вечер. Есть текстовый файл, в котором все строки выглядят примерно так.

> HEADER:  DNPP/AD072T1005E/UKRCBK1V5131S553/103
>   15-05-02  02:17:58  3479                               3095/02123
>   HF.ARCHIVE-68646
>
> DATA:  AUDIT ERROR DISPLAY    AUDIT NAME = IPPRTSTA       UNIT = LTG-
>   1-3     RESULT = ERROR CORRECTED                   ERROR NUMBER : 33
>   ERROR COUNT: 3           ERROR SUB NUM: 0      LTGINT  DLUINT  V5IFINT
>   PORT   PORT TYPE      EQUIPMENT NUMBER 
>   -------+-------+-------+-------+----------      -----------------------   67      28              300     10             EQN :    70- 2- 5- 4 
>                                                   LTG :          LC:
>                                                   DLU :          LC: 
>                                                   V5IF:          LC:    FAULT INFORMATION 
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------  H'FFFF001D 10FFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF 01FFFFFF FFFFFFFF 
>   H'00000000 82030110 00080200 F240FFFF 00401880 000200F1 82FFFF01 
>   H'00470000 00430000 3B183B18 8000E180 8000E180 00002FFF FFFFFFFF 
>   H'80FFFF00 00FFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF 
>   H'00FFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF 
>   H'00000000 82030000 00080200 E200FFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
>
> ```
>                                                                 LTG       CALL STATE
> ```
>
> ------+------+-----------
>
> ---
>
> END TEXT 6766

Примечательно, что каждый такой элемент начинается с HEADER и заканчивается END TEXT.

Вопрос: есть ли в C# такая функция, которая читала начиная "от" и "до" какого-то элемента поочерёдно?

Comment: Текстовые файлы читаются по строкам: while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)

Comment: Переформатируй вопрос с использованием тега code. А то я не пойму, стрелки - это часть формата или часть ворматирования.

Answer (score 2):

Такой функции нет. Читаете файл построчно и проверяете строки на `line.StartWith("HEADER")` и `line.StartWith("END TEXT")`.

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("c:\\test.txt"))
{
    if (line.StartWith("HEADER"))
    {
        //...
    }
    else if (line.StartWith("END TEXT"))
    {
        //...
    }
}
```